# "Site permissions" goes to error page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, permissions, custom-masterpage, system-master-page

I have created SharePoint 2013 custom Master Page.

I have applied that Master Page into system pages. When I click on **Site permissions** in **Site Setting** page it redirects to error page.

I don't know what's am I missing.

Suggest any idea to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you please post the snap of your error? Also this is happening with only Site Permission page?

Comment: Assuming you receive some Correlation ID, you can track your ULS logs to check for the events matching the ID. They should detail more about what's exactly wrong with your master page.

Comment: You could use an ULS-Viewer (i.e. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020) to check the logs.. It's hard to "guess" what the problem could be...

Comment: Thanks, i have refered ULS logs , finaly i found the code that i missed in custom master page.that is "<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarTop" runat="server" />".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per your description it seems that there is a problem in your custom Master Page configuration.

Also it seems that only **Site Permission** page is throwing an error.

So the possible problem is your custom Master Page is missing some Site Permission relevant tag.

Please compare it with the existing `Seatle` Master Page and check for the missing tag.